# Error with the pow function

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int decimal, count, binary, digit;
    printf("Enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);
    count = 0; binary = 0;
    while (decimal > 0) {
        digit = decimal % 2;
        binary = binary + digit * pow(10, count);
        decimal = decimal / 2;
        ++count;
    }
    printf("Binary form : %d", binary);
}
```

I used the above code to convert Decimal to binary. However, the problem is the output.

```
Input           : 12
Expected Output : 1100
Actual Output   : 1099
```

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rMHt.png

This problem persists for other inputs too. Only 8 gives the correct output.

So can someone explain why this happens? This error also shows up in C++, when I port it there.

PS: This error also pops up while using `pow` in checking if a number is Armstrong and if its a palindrome.

Comment: are you sure ? that's not even possible ...

Comment: https://repl.it/LLhY/0 I get `1100`

Comment: You don't want to use `pow` for this sort of thing.  Keep a running multiplier, multiplying by `2` or `10` every time.  `pow` has inaccuracies.

Comment: See [is-floating-point-math-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You probably don't want to convert the number into a decimal number that looks like a binary number at all. Binary is just a representation of the same number, so you probably want a string.

Comment: PS integer is not very good to keep this form of the "binary".  for 64bit integer the max number is 524287 for 32 bit 1023

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from the limited precision of the `double` arithmetic. `pow(10, count)` may be computed as `exp(log(10) * count)`, which can produce a value that is very close but different from the actual integer result. If this value is smaller than the mathematical value, converting to `int` does not round to closest, it takes the integral part that will be the previous integer, hence `99` instead of `100`.

You should instead use integer arithmetics:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int decimal, binary, digit, pow10;
    printf("Enter the number : ");
    if (scanf("%d", &decimal) == 1) {
        binary = 0;
        pow10 = 1;
        while (decimal > 0) {
            digit = decimal % 2;
            decimal /= 2;
            binary = binary + digit * pow10;
            pow10 *= 10;
        }
        printf("Binary form: %d\n", binary);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that there are some other issues in your code:

- The prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`.
- You should print a newline at the end of your output.
- You should test the return value of `scanf()`.
- Your method is intrinsically limited to integer values below `2047` (with 32-bit `int`).

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long decimal;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    if (scanf("%llu", &decimal) == 1) {
        char binary[sizeof(decimal) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
        char *p = binary + sizeof(binary);
        *--p = '\0';
        while (decimal > 1) {
            *--p = '0' + (decimal & 1); // '0' or '1' for all encodings
            decimal >>= 1;
        }
        *--p = '0' + decimal;
        printf("Binary form: %s\n", binary);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that pow doesn't have to be implemented in that way, although it's very likely it is - particularly with IEEE754.

Comment: I would say "limited to integer values 1023 and below".  With greater values,   `pow10 *= 10;` overflows.

Comment: @chux: good point: my implementation has this problem, but the OP's method could go up to 2047 if `pow(10, count)` behaved correctly.

Comment: Now this is heading towards canonicity, it might be worth mentioning that `'0' + decimal` will work with any encoding supported by C.

Comment: @Bathsheba: done. `"01"[decimal & 1]` would work too, without the assumption `'1' == '0' + 1`, but the assumption is OK for all encodings and this alternative is less efficient.

Answer (score 3):

`pow(x, y)` is most likely implemented as `exp(y * log(x))` which can go off for surprisingly small integral arguments. This manifests itself in a particularly pathological way if the result is truncated to an integer.

The moral of the story is to avoid the `pow` function when working in integer arithmetic.

In your case maintaining a running coefficient with successive multiplications by `10` would be appropriate. Just be careful you don't overflow your `int` type; the upper limit could be as small as `32767`.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding mixing floats & integers. PS using of the `pow` function in such a simple code is a sign of the extreme laziness.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first problem is your types - you seem to want to build an *integer* representation of a *binary* number, and you're also using pow, which has a signature of:

```
double pow(double x, double y)
```

So you're adding a *double float* to an *integer*. Are you sure you want to do that?

You're probably better off doing the divide by/mod by base loop and building a string and printing that. That's answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111150/changing-a-number-between-arbitrary-bases

Also, big or little endianness may bite you but is that in the scope of your homework question?

Comment: These considerations are interesting, but not a precise answer to the OP's problem